# When does $g \in H \implies [g] \subseteq H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

Suppose $G$ is a group with an equivalence relation defined on it; let $[g]$ denote the equivalence class of $g \in G$. In reading some group theory texts I have sometimes seen the following property: we have some subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that the following holds:

> If $g \in H$, then $[g] \subseteq H$.

In other words, if an element of the group can be found in the subgroup $H$, then it brings along its entire equivalence class into $H$ as well. (And the converse trivially holds because $g \in [g]$.)

Are there any fairly general conditions on the equivalence relation and/or on the subgroup $H$ (or the group $G$) in order for this property to hold? Is there a name for this sort of property? What are some important/common examples of this phenomenon?

Comment: Note that $[g]=gH$ is a coset, so of course we have this, since $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: You are taking about a very specific equivalence relation. In general, this may not hold...

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how the question was meant, sorry. I suspect that it is about cosets, though.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Me neither... the question strongly miss context...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for pointing out that special case. I know my question was really general... maybe I was curious about what are some specific examples, and trying to identify what they have in common that might make them possess such a property

Comment: It's a kinda intuitive that the equivalence relation which ensures this condition must be, say, "$H$-dependent" (in fact it is $a\sim b \iff ab^{-1}\in H$). Therefore, I don't see how a different one, not involving $H$, could ensure that as well.

Comment: *Any* partition of $G$ induces an equivalence relation. Unless $H=G$, you can *always* define an equivalence relation on $G$ such that there exists $h\in H$ with $[g]\not\subseteq H$: pick $x\in G$, $x\notin H$, and define an equivalence relation in which the equivalence classes are all singletons except for $[e]=[x]=\{e,x\}$. Then $e\in H$ but $[e]$ is not contained in $H$.